# Logistic regression with BIC: what is my sample size?

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, sample-size, bic

I'd like to compare logistic regression models using the BIC. I have 600 data points, but only 30 of these belong to the class of interest. To calculate the [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) I need to know my sample size, $N$.

In my case, is my sample size 600 or 30?  Should the BIC calculation use the total size of my dataset (600), or just the number of positive samples (30)?

Comment: BIC, AIC look at all your data.

Comment: How many points did you train your classifier on? This is your sample size.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used all 600 points when fitting your model, then the sample size $n$ is 600.